# Integrate OSExcelBundle

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I tried to install OSExcelBundle (https://github.com/ouardisoft/OSExcelBundle) on Symfony 2.1 by following the README :

1. Add this line to the require option in your composer.json file:  "os/excel-bundle": "dev-master"
   OK
2. Add autoloader for PHPExcel in app/autoloader.php :  `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/os/php-excel/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';` There is no app/autoloader.php in symfony 2.1 - I tried to add the line in app/autoload.php - without success.
3. This works : `php composer.phar install`

But without step 2 this does not work : I get this error message :

> You have requested a non-existent service "os.excel"

If someone can give me a hint would be nice ...

Edit : 
I added this line in AppKernel : new OS\ExcelBundle\OSExcelBundle(),
and so the bundle seems to be taken in account.

Nevertheless now I get this error :
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in ..\vendor\os\excel-bundle\OS\ExcelBundle\Excel\Excel.php on line 29

So I really need to know where I can declare PHPExcel !

Answer (score 0):

I installed an other bundle : ExcelBundle
This one no problem to install (???)
And  !!! : it resolves my problem with the other bundle - because it made PHPExcel available
So I can go on ...